# is there any performance benefits in coding java style in groovy/grails?

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-2.2

You can specify types and also use interfaces in groovy. So in other words you can code in java style in groovy. Coming from java background some people find it comfortable to treat groovy as java and start development in java style. I am wondering whether specifying types and coding java style  has any benefits in groovy in terms of speed and performance or can we get rid of specifying the types and code pure groovy style if there is no performance difference?

here is a service method with java style

```
Reservation makeReservation(Sale sale, Buyable buyable, BigDecimal serviceFeePayment = BigDecimal.ZERO,
            Integer quantity = 1, BigDecimal price = null, Date expiration = null, Boolean includedInRegistration = false, String initials = ''){
```

here is without specifying types

```
def makeReservation(sale, buyable, serviceFeePayment = BigDecimal.ZERO,
            quantity = 1, price = null, expiration = null, includedInRegistration = false, initials = ''){
```

I appreciate any insights. Thanks!

Comment: If you want to write Java, you can as well put .java files in your src/groovy if you want the benefits for it. I'd put the types on each function anyways, as it helps the developers and whether that has performance implications i'd not care - most likely way more time is spent creating a reservation than microbenchmarking around this.

Comment: The only difference I have noticed in Groovy when using def vs actual data types - and this is sometimes the IDE's capabilities - when you declare an object type Reservation res = getSomeRes. The res object is able to resolve the inner methods or available calls in groovy in sts it all goes blue or recognised sometimes as def - you get underlines and no actual understanding so far as the ide is concerned - I mean  res.someMethod would come back recognised declared

Comment: It's not just being nice to other developers by declaring the types, it's yourself as well when you come back to the code in x months or even years. When the types are there you know immediately what Objects they should be.